# Comparing a website migration result (while running both sites in parallel)

Tags: bash, xpath, web, migration

I'm migrating a client's home grown site into Drupal 7. The process is taking a while -- design decisions, a few new requirements, etc. I'm sure you've all been there.

I started working on a tool to (a) get a list of URLs paths from the old database, (b)
get each page's content from both the Drupal site and the old site, (c) do a xpath query on the pages to get content of div#maincontent and div#main using [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), and (d) save that data in new.txt and old.txt files -- all while keeping a similar folder structure as the site for reference.

**gather_data.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# get URLS
urls=$(ssh user@old_ser "~/data_urls.sh" | egrep "^\/" | sort -u)

# clear out current working folder
rm -rf ./working

# loop through paths
for i in $urls
do  

    # screen status update, set storage area with url_path in folder path, make folder
    echo $i
    storage_area=./working/$i/
    mkdir -p $storage_area


    # strip trailing space
    i=${i%/}

    # pull and and run xpath query
    xidel http://old_server$i  -e '//div[@id="maincontent"]//p' > $storage_area/old.txt
    xidel http://new_server$i -e '//div[@id="content"]//p' > $storage_area/new.txt

    # run a compare and output data into cmp.cmp
    cmp $storage_area/old.txt $storage_area/new.txt > $storage_area/cmp.cmp

done
```

The secondary script loops through the results of the cmp.cmp files.

**run_diff.sh**

```
echo "------------------------------------------------------- "
echo "The following may have differences in content based on wdiff analysis"

for i in `find ./working/ -type d`; do

  better_url_name=`echo $i | sed -e 's#\./working##g'`


  echo -e "\e[1;37m"
  echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo http://old_server$better_url_name
  echo http://new_server$better_url_name
  echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo -e "\e[00m"
  wdiff -3s $i/old.txt $i/new.txt  | colordiff
done
```

The result of the above produces something like the following.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
http://old_server/career_services/career_fair.php
http://new_server/career_services/career_fair.php
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


======================================================================
 [-9. 
School-] {+9.School+}
======================================================================
 [-Imagination
April-] {+ImaginationApril+}
======================================================================
 [-contract.
April-] {+contract.April+}
======================================================================

{+ +}
======================================================================
./working/epics/career_services/career_fair.php/old.txt: 1001 words  995 99% common  0 0% deleted  6 1% changed
./working/epics/career_services/career_fair.php/new.txt: 999 words  995 100% common  1 0% inserted  3 0% changed
```

***My Questions:***

- How do I ignore these false positives?
- How do I filter out for spaces and return marks?
- Is this the right approach? Should I abandoned this methodology for another that would yield better results?

Answer (score 0):

With `diff` command you can use the following options -

```
   -b  --ignore-space-change
         Ignore changes in the amount of white space.

   -w  --ignore-all-space
         Ignore all white space.

   -B  --ignore-blank-lines
         Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

       --strip-trailing-cr
         Strip trailing carriage return on input.
```